# PHP and MySQL to perform a join on a MAX column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I've read a few of the similar threads on here and after many hours of banging my head, I *still* can't get this to work.

I have 2 tables within MySQL:
   - bookings
   - booking_status_history

The structure and data of the booking table:

```
id pt_id client_id timestamp           notes
62    30        15 2015-02-02 07:00:00
```

The structure and data of the booking_status_history table:
(note booking_id is a foreign key to the booking table above)

```
id booking_id timestamp           description                                  details       status
11         62 2015-02-02 00:40:42 Client made Booking (pending)                test_detailsi pending
12         62 2015-02-02 00:40:45 PT confirmed booking (confirmed)             test_details2 pending
18         62 2015-02-02 02:45:15 Client cancelled Booking (Medical Emergency) test_details3 pending
```

What I am trying to achieve is getting the LATEST value from the status column for each booking (this test data only shows 1 booking and 3 history values).

At the moment I have only achieved pulling back all of the history results and not just the latest row.

I am using the following PHP MySQLi library: https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class#join-method

This is my current code which seems to return all of the history. I've tried using variations of MAX and GROUPBY as I've seen work for others in older threads but for some reason I just can't apply it to this scenario.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());

$this->db->join("booking_status_history h", "b.id=h.booking_id", "LEFT");
$this->db->where('client_id', $id_param);
$this->db->where('b.timestamp', $date, ">");
$this->db->where('h.status', 'pending');
$this->db->orderBy("b.timestamp","desc");
$next_booking = $this->db->get("booking b", NULL, "b.*, h.status");

return $next_booking;
```

As you can see from the output below, this is returning all 3 history values:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 62 
        [pt_id] => 30 
        [client_id] => 15 
        [timestamp] => 2015-02-02 07:00:00 
        [notes] => [status] => pending 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [id] => 62 
        [pt_id] => 30 
        [client_id] => 15 
        [timestamp] => 2015-02-02 07:00:00 
        [notes] => [status] => pending 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [id] => 62 
        [pt_id] => 30 
        [client_id] => 15 
        [timestamp] => 2015-02-02 07:00:00 
        [notes] => [status] => pending 
    ) 
)
```

I appreciate not everyone is going to be familiar with this PHP library so even if someone can explain it to me via raw SQL, that would be awesome.

What I am *trying* to do is (in pseudo code):

```
SELECT everything 
FROM bothtables 
WHERE booking.id=booking_status_history.booking_id 
    AND latest entry in booking_status_table
```

I hope that makes sense. It's 5am and I've been up all night having a huge code block.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a SQLFiddle for this problem,please? I'm resonably certain (from what I read) that you can alleviate your problem by ordering by the timestamp column in descending order. Then again it is entirely possible I misread it. Perhaps even a `GROUP BY id` ?

Comment: I tried to post an SQLFiddle but it moaned about

'Schema Creation Failed: Invalid default value for 'timestamp': '

Even though both timestamp cols have a default of 'current_timestamp'

I've tried all variations of sorting via timestamps and I still had no luck. I just can't seem to pull only the single latest row when it finds multiple rows in the booking_status_history table.

Comment: It groaned about what?

Comment: Perhaps add the SQL, with some dummy insert data and I'll see if I can get a fiddle working? (just an export in Phpmyadmin would be fine for me)

Comment: Here's a pastebin of the phpmyadmin export:

http://pastebin.com/kE37kkX8

I'm most likely just being a complete dunce but I'll blame the lack of coffee!

Comment: If you could - I believe I've got something working, but I need some test data to make sure that adding more data won't totally screw with it, can you pastebin a bit more (preferably with a different booking_id?)

Comment: Here's a fresh export with more data! :-)

http://pastebin.com/6v27JUjk

Comment: Just as I feared - it messed it up. Reworking.

Comment: I *think* I might have cracked it...

Does this work for you?

SELECT b.*, h.booking_id, h.details, h.status FROM booking b JOIN booking_status_history h ON b.id = h.booking_id WHERE h.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM booking_status_history WHERE booking_id = b.id)

Comment: With the test data I've got it works for me - hopefully it works for OP. If it does, you should post it as an answer to that OP can mark it

Comment: Hi. For a different view, how about keeping last booking_status_id in booking table?

Answer (score 1):

This is what seems to have cracked it for me! Many thanks to Jhecht for spending time helping me out :-)

```
SELECT b.*, h.booking_id, h.details, h.status FROM booking b JOIN booking_status_history h ON b.id = h.booking_id WHERE h.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM booking_status_history WHERE booking_id = b.id)
```

Comment: An uncorelated subquery, like the example provided in the manual, will typically perform much better than this. BTW, this is the most frequently asked question on SO under the MySQL tag. Occasionally, it gets answered correctly too. Just sayin'

Answer (score 0):

You can go for comparison with id from status table.It will go like this.

```
SELECT * FROM booking_status_history_table bs,booking_table bt 
WHERE bs.booking_id=bt.id 
and bs.id in 
(select max(id) from booking_status_history_table group by booking_id)
```

Comment: Id is a primary key and hence it has to be always unique. And talking about timestamp it is usually practised that no two entries are made together that is transaction control is done. Hence two tuples having same timestamp is also not possible. Hence I hope that the answer provided is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The stock solution looks like this...

```
SELECT b.*
     , x.timestamp
     , x.description
     , x.status
  FROM booking b
  JOIN booking_status_history x
    ON x.booking_id = b.id
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT booking_id,MAX(id) max_id FROM booking_status_history GROUP BY booking_id ) y
    ON y.booking_id = x.booking_id
   AND y.max_id = x.id;
```